# Network Communication - queue processing thread/task or?

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have an application that is sending messages over a socket from different threads. I create my own wrapper for the socket that enables me to extend functionality.

- on new SocketConnection() it returns only one instance based on IP and port. So if some other thread tries to create instance of IP 1.1.1.1 and port 1000 every time it gets the same instance if it already exists. (Single instance for one device.)
- Auto connect
- State machine for connection etc.

Every unique instance has a send message queue (from higher app) and has a Task/Thread that is running in a loop and checking if something is in the queue to be sent, then processes socket.send (if queue is not empty). When the send is successful or fails then respond using a callback to the process that added the message to the queue.

I'm not sure if this is a good solution to have for each unique instance a Task/Thread running in a loop. Imagine I have 100 endpoint devices (machines) and my app is from different threads sending data to these devices.

If I have 100 devices to communicate with, than I have 100 unique instances with 100 threads/Tasks running in loop and processing queues.

App generates to one of these devices (for example 50 requests to send from different upper threads) to destination device with IP 1.1.1.1 port 70. My unique class for this IP, adds this to messages queue and thread-loop of this instance, processes these messages one by one. Upper level just gets callback if socket.send() was OK or failed.

Is this good way how to process many connection? The same way I'm receiving responses from devices. (The Device is a server.)

What I know now is that using create new thread is faster than using Task for loops in each instance. Is it better to use timer interrupt? Or what's the best way to process incoming communications?

Are there any patterns how to do that?

Comment: This question seems a bit opinion/implementation dependent based.

Comment: This is a really really complex topic, and you often need to consider send and receive *completely* separately (they have different characteristics), *and* you need to make decisions that are contextual based on the scenario. This would be based on things like the level of expected concurrency per socket, how the replies are matched with requests, whether you're using a synchronous vs asynchronous API at the call-site, whether you prefer calls to return promptly but queue the write, vs return once they've *done* their write, vs a hybrid model, etc. There's *lots* of trade-offs here.

Comment: The one thing I will say: a thread per socket is almost always a bad idea (unless maybe you have 3 sockets)... but when you move away from that, you start getting into topics like "thread pool saturation", "task-based thread theft" and custom thread models/pools. It gets *really* complex to do a good job here. So another key question is: "how deep do you want to get here?" - you kinda need to either go with "meh, simple is probably fine", or "really, really, really deep" - anything in the middle will usually suck. And it isn't practical to give a "really, really, really deep" answer here.

Comment: This question may suit better [another site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: If you want something to consider: it sounds like StackExchange.Redis works a lot like you're describing; it uses a socket or two per endpoint, and has outbound and inbound queue semantics (with the hybrid "can I get exclusive access right now? if so, write, else queue" approach), async plus sync caller APIs, ordered reply matching, custom thread pools, thread-theft safety etc. **LOTS** of moving parts. The receive works on the "pipelines" async IO model with a custom thread-pool.

Comment: I was thinking about another idea..

My connection class handler will have one main loop thread as manager...

If the data flow is low (queues for each connections are mostly empty).. than only this main thread process connection in for each (I have list of connection)..

If the queue of some connection is to big (or transfer rate) than i will start special thread for this connection..

In this situation the system can adapt. Yes this will add same delay or latency but looking to resources this is maybe the the another way..